# Grub Freezes on Dualboot only when switching to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have Ubuntu and Win10 on a dualboot setup. Windows is my standart boot, and i have to switch to Ubuntu in the OS-select screen in grub. Sometimes when i boot from windows to linux  (and only if windows was running before, and i want to swithc to linux, as of now), the computer freezes when i move the OS-selection (by using arrow keys) from win10 (last entry) to ubuntu (first entry).
This has not happened before, and started happening a week ago. Windows fast-boot ist disabled, and the linux system-time is set to local.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I had both OS's installed in Legacy mode. I managed to solve the problem following these steps:

1. Delete Ubuntu partitions and reset Windows Boot Manager as default.
2. Convert disk from MBR to GPT partition style (to shift from BIOS to UEFI) and reconfigure the firmware to boot in UEFI mode.
3. Reinstall Ubuntu alongside Windows in UEFI mode.

Don't know if you are in Legacy mode too but hope this helps!